# Is there any "standard" way to use sudo with a wrapper?

Tags: shell, sudo

For example, if I want to take the output of my `dmesg` I have to invoke it with elevated permission using `sudo dmesg`.

Now, say I want to monitor the output, I can put it in `watch` using either `watch -n 1 sudo dmesg` or `sudo watch -n 1 dmesg`. They both output the same thing.

My questions are:

1. Is there any example that using `sudo` in different orders lead to different outputs?
2. Is there any "standard" or formal notation in these cases? Should I wrap `sudo` before the whole wrapper, or should I put `sudo` at the command that requires elevated permission?

Comment: There's no pipe here.

Comment: @muru you're right. I called wrapper wrong. what a shame.

Comment: The point was to see if you actually had some application of a pipe and if you forgot to mention it.

Answer (score 2):

You are using a wrapper, not a pipe. Wrappers will carry their permissions with them.

In this instance for purely security reasons, please use

```
sudo watch dmesg
```

instead of

```
watch sudo dmesg
```

so that you trigger the `sudo` authentication only once. Otherwise it will continually refresh your authentication as `sudo` runs every second. If you then step away and someone walks up and `^C`'s your command they will be able to immediately `sudo` something else regardless of how long its been since you hit enter on that command.

In general, every command that needs elevation needs `sudo`:

```
sudo command1 | sudo command2
```

In the case of a wrapper, elevating a process will elevate any new processes that that process spawns. Only exception there are things that automatically run as another, non root user. Services that run under their own user, for example.

If you have several commands that are piped into eachother, all requiring elevation, it's usual to see them wrapped in an elevated bash sub-shell:

```
sudo bash -c "command1 | command2"
```

Comment: You're right. I confused wrapper and pipe. BTW, thank you very much, it makes sense that I should trigger `sudo` once.